# Most efficient and cheapest way to drive a high power and consumption giant dimming LED matrix

Tags: power-supply, mains, led-driver, led-strip, led-matrix

I'm building a giant LED matrix for an art project.

Each "pixel" is a 12V RGB LED strip consuming ~23W, and has to be fully dimming controllable.

We're talking about 768 pixels with a total current draw near to 18kW at max power (RGB fully ON for white color). That's a lot so it needs to be "efficient" with a component cost that keeps it relatively economical.

What would be the best way to drive that thing? The project will be controlled by Arduino via shift registers. The mains is 3phased 380AC or AC230V (Europe).

In a small circuit I would use BJT transistors or any MOSFET I have lying around (TIP120 for example) after any suitable AC to DC transformer/driver in a configuration like this:
[image]

1. What parts could I use in "C" to not waste too much energy? MOSFETS, BJTs, Buck Converters, what?
2. Do you recommend me a power supply format like the one pictured in part A? I've used meanwell led drivers in other projects (I'm assuming they're more efficient) and they have a different form.
3. What would be the best DC voltage to power this? (I'm assuming 12V for cheaper led strips, but perhaps 1€/1US$ extra for every 5meters of 24V is better in the long run)
4. Do you have any Shift register (part B) model recommendation? This project needs only 2304 channels haha :_) (768"pixels" *3 channels).

Comment: The units of power are Watts, abbreviated W. Not 'Wh' or 'W-h'.

Comment: `a total current draw near to 18kW·h at max power` shouldn't be that much with multiplexed driving. One "pixel" will be on at a time, am I correct?

Comment: [A metal oxide semiconductor field effect transistor (MOSFET) is a transistor.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET)  The other transistors you mentioned are bipolar junction transistors (BJT.)

Comment: Using some programmable LEDs, like WS2812, you may avoid using of lot elements.

Comment: @KevinWhite I edited the question. Thank you

Comment: The average power outlet will only give you about 2.4kW. 18kW will most likely require a 3phase feed.

Comment: @RohatKılıç 18kW is 5 times the max power in a conventional apartment (3.5kW). Won't all lights (or their drivers) draw electricity at the same time even if multiplexed? I need all the lights to be "on" for the human eye and cameras.

Comment: @JRE thanks for the correction about BJTs. Edited

Comment: You might want to find yourself an electronic engineer as there will be legal and safety issues that need to be complied with as well as the significant cost of the parts. Note that DC current is DC current. There is no ‘best’.

Comment: You may want to consider building this with professional DMX dimmers, responsible for subzones. Say a bank of something like these: https://www.proled.com/en-DE/products/controls-power-supplies-accessories/pwm-dimmers-controls/dmx-pwm-dimmer-32-channel/ And then conventional three phase rack PDUs to distribute power to them.

Comment: Additionally, 18kW is a lot of heat. Have you considered how you are going to handle heat dissipation from the LEDs?

Comment: @Kartman yes. it will be installed in a three-phase supplied building. I can read, LEARN and document myself, but I won't be able to pay for an engineer for this project. Just the components will be a fair sum. With "best" I meant "best component picking and distribution". This learning can (surely will) lead to future projects

Comment: @MakerCult Right. I thought there's going to be some sort of multiplexing as the application involves an LED "matrix". It's still possible to tackle the potential flickering image issue on cameras but it's up to you. As for driving, depending on the driving technique, one row, one column or a single pixel can be on at a time. If you want all of them to be on at the same time, get yourself ready for anything.

Comment: @MakerCult Even if you go for building everything yourself, look at DMX. to multiple microcontrollers responsible for zones. It looks more complex than shift registers on the surface, but the RS-485 differential signalling makes it a lot easier to transform you system into 18-36 subunits, which means that the power consumption per unit becomes a lot more manageable (12v AC-DC adaptors are a lot more common than 18kW ones, and 36 500w units will probably be a lot cheaper, and you dont have to deal with a 1500A power rail). Once you have the subunits, with 12v supplies, PWM dimming isn't to bad.

Comment: @user1937198 I've updated the question with an schematic and more concrete questions. Commercial DMX are out of reach. You can design and order factory assembled PCBs for the entire project for the price of only one commercial DMX (I would need 96 of them! LOL!). The heat dissipation won't be a problem, but that's a good observation.

Comment: I don't think user1937198 is proposing a commercial DMX setup. You can put a DMX library on an Arduino, then have multiple of these DMX Arduinos with each one responsible for a smaller zone within your overall project. Configure one additional DMX Arduino as the "master" to control all the slaves. It'll probably be far easier to design, build & test a smaller zone device and then copy it *X* times than to design, build & test the whole thing in one.

Comment: This project will be many times too big for your level of experience. The  price for all the needed parts will be very high and the risk to loose all that money is much too high. You need to start with much smaller projects to get enough experience.

Comment: Pretty much exactly as brhans describes, and there are standard libraries/transceivers for DMX and you don't have to deal with the separate supply issues. As for drivers, there are integrated chips like the allegro a8522 (https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/regulate/led-drivers/led-drivers-for-backlighting/a8522), that can drive the LEDs directly based off an I2C bus, which is probably going to be far cheaper than any attempt to build direct dimming from arduinos. (You might get cheaper if you can use raw microcontrollers to generate the PWM signals).

Comment: Your schematic is wrong, the third phase is not used. A load of this size should use all three phases symmetric. If your mains is in Europe, the voltage between a phase and earth is 230 V and between two phases is 400 V.

Comment: @MakerCult The external LED display "billboards" that have animated displays alongside roadways/freeways use power at the rate you seem to suggest (I'm not believing your numbers yet -- separate issue.) They are ***very*** difficult to properly design. And no matter how smart you think you are, you will either have a long "on-ramp" of learning ahead or else you will need help. (Unless you are an unparalleled super-genius.)

Comment: @periblepsis The whole high power issue can be bypassed by using commercial parts. Putting together a 25A three phase power distribution setup using commercial PDUs, 12v supplies and DMX dimmers isn't too bad. The issue is the parts are expensive because you are paying for someone to have spend the time designing them in a safe way, and you need a lot of space for all the parts. Probably roughly 4-8 racks worth. Putting the whole thing together from discrete's is a nightmare which is why at least some billboards use the modular design of multiple panels on separate supplys run off PDUs.

Comment: @user1937198 I'm **very well** aware of the modular design used on billboards.

Comment: @MakerCult. No doubt you can read and learn, but I don’t want you to learn the hard way. In many countries there are laws regarding electrical wiring and require it to be done by qualified people. Sure, you can read the electrical standard and wire your system up, but that doesn’t make it legal. If you are doing your art installation in a public place you may require insurance and a third party audit of your installation. I would suggest you investigate this as it may have a significant effect on how you implement your hardware.

Comment: 18KW is a lot of light, and at 12V its a lot of copper wiring, Is this setup going to be distrubuted across a bullding? it may be wise to place the 12V supplies close to the LEDs to reduce copper costs.